# how do control the state for multiple component with one function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have one simple app that include 3 identical button and when I click the button, onClick event should trigger to display one `span`. for now, I have use one `one state` to control `span` show or not and once I click any one of button all `span` show. How can I implement the code, so when I click the button, only the correspond `span` display

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Popup = (props) => {
  return <span {...props}>xxx</span>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}> Show popup1</button>
      <Popup hidden={isOpen} />
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}> Show popup2</button>
      <Popup hidden={isOpen} />
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}> Show popup3</button>
      <Popup hidden={isOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-fermi-je8lr?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rethink how the components are used.
Since there is a repeating logic and interface, it should be separated to a different component.

```
const Popup = (props) => {
  return <span {...props}>xxx</span>;
};

interface Props {
  buttonText: string
  popupProps?: any
}

const PopupFC: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>{props.buttonText}</button>
      <Popup hidden={isOpen} {...props.popupProps} />
    </>
  )
}
export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PopupFC buttonText="Show popup1" />
      <PopupFC buttonText="Show popup2" />
      <PopupFC buttonText="Show popup3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: but I would like when I click PopupFC1, message `Show popup1` popup then if I click PopupFC2, message `Show popup1` disappear then `Show popup2` popup

Comment: Then you should consider using a Context Provider or trigger the close form the parent compoent

Answer (score 2):

If each `Popup` needs its own `isOpen` state, it would not be possible to achieve with a single boolean state.
Perhaps converting both the button and the span to a single component and letting each `Popup` component handle its own `isOpen`:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Popup = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>{props.children}</button>
      {isOpen && <span {...props}>xxx</span>}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Popup>Show popup 1</Popup>
      <Popup>Show popup 2</Popup>
      <Popup>Show popup 3</Popup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens simply because you are using the same state "isOpen" for all buttons,
once you click any one of them it reflects all buttons because it's the same value.
you could solve this using Custom Hook since you repeat the logic  or you could  separate them into small components

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you only want one popup to be open at a time.  That was not clear in your original question so the other answers don't address this.

Right now you are just storing a value of `isOpen` that is `true` or `false`.  That is not enough information.  How do you know *which* popup is open?

If you want to show just one at a time, you can instead store the number or name (any sort of unique id) for the popup which is currently open.

We make the `Popup` a "controlled component" where instead of managing its own internal `isOpen` state, it receives and updates that information via `props`.

The `App` component is responsible for managing which popup is open and passing the right props to each `Popup` component.  Since we are doing the same thing for multiple popups, I moved that logic into a `renderPopup` helper function.

**Popup**

```
interface PopupProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  open: () => void;
  close: () => void;
  label: string;
}

const Popup = ({ isOpen, open, close, label }: PopupProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={open}> Show {label}</button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div>
          <h1>{label}</h1>
          <span>xxx</span>
          <button onClick={close}>Close</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

**App**

```
export default function App() {
  // store the label of the popup which is open,
  // or `null` if all are closed
  const [openId, setOpenId] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const renderPopup = (label: string) => {
    return (
      <Popup
        label={label}
        isOpen={openId === label} // check if this popup is the one that's open
        open={() => setOpenId(label)} // open by setting the `openId` to this label
        close={() => setOpenId(null)} // calling `close` closes all
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderPopup("Popup 1")}
      {renderPopup("Popup 2")}
      {renderPopup("Popup 3")}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-66068017-kg6vu?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most sophisticated way of doing things, but it solves the problem with a simple solution:

```
const Popup = (props) => {
  return <span {...props}>xxx</span>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true, true, true);

  const handleOnClick = (index) => {
    const newIsOpen = [true, true, true];
    newIsOpen[index] = !newIsOpen;
    setIsOpen(newIsOpen);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => handleOnClick(0)}> Show popup1</button>
      <Popup hidden={isOpen[0]} />
      <button onClick={() => handleOnClick(1)}> Show popup2</button>
      <Popup hidden={isOpen[1]} />
      <button onClick={() => handleOnClick(2)}> Show popup3</button>
      <Popup hidden={isOpen[2]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```